# Handling model specific actions vs database actions

Tags: go, webserver

I am having some issues when it comes to model design, specifically handling **Model specific actions** vs **Database actions**. A good example would be my User model.

When creating a user in my DB, I want to:

1. Verify the password meets criteria (Model action)
2. Create the digest (Model action)
3. Set timestamps (model action)
4. Save the Email, Digest, and Timestamps to the DB (DB Action)

When testing, I obviously want to have a set of unit test for all 4, however #4 has calls to the other 3, something I don’t want to retest, or risk having #4 test fail if any of those 3 do.

I have come up with creating a separate Interface for ModelActions vs StoreActions, and sending the UserAction interface to a store action when needed, however as I write it out, I am already sensing some serious code smell.

```
type User struct {
        ID                   int    `json:"id"`
        Email                string `json:"email"`
        Password             string `json:"password"`
        ConfirmationPassword string `json:"confirmationPassword"`
        passwordDigest       string `json:"-"`
        CreatedAt            time.Time `json:"createdAt,omitempty"`
        ModifiedAt           time.Time `json:"modifiedAt,omitempty"`
}

//UserStore is the interface for all User functions that interact with the database
type UserStore interface {
        GetUserByEmailAndPassword(email, password string) (User, error)
        UpdatePassword(u UserAction, previousPassword, password, confirmationPassword string) error
        UserExists(email string) (bool, error)
        CreateUser(u UserAction) error
}

// I am going against design Principles by having GetID, GetEmail, since JSON unmarshalling needs the struct fields to be capitalized, which is already a warning sign for me

type UserAction interface {
        GetID() int
        GetEmail() string
        Timestamps() (time.Time, time.Time)
        SetID(id int)
        SetTimestamps()
        SetPassword(password, confirmation string)
        SetDigest(digest string)
        CreateDigest() (string, error)
        VerifyPassword() error
        ComparePassword(password string) error
}

// Example of UserActions
func (u *User) CreateDigest() (string, error) {
        var digest string
        if err := u.VerifyPassword(); err != nil {
                return digest, err
        }

        passwordByte, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(u.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
                return digest, err
        }

        digest = string(passwordByte)
        return digest, nil
}

func (u *User) VerifyPassword() error {
        if len(u.Password) < 6 {
                return &modelError{"Password", "must be at least 6 characters long"}
        }

        if u.Password != u.ConfirmationPassword {
                return &modelError{"ConfirmationPassword", "does not match Password"}
        }

        return nil
}

// Example of DB Action
func (db *DB) CreateUser(ua UserAction) error {
        if exists, err := db.UserExists(ua.GetEmail()); err != nil {
                return err
        } else if exists {
                return &modelError{"Email", "already exists in the system"}
        }

        // set password
        digest, err := ua.CreateDigest()
        if  err != nil {
                return err
        }

        ua.SetDigest(digest)
        ua.SetTimestamps()

        createdAt, modifiedAt := ua.Timestamps()

        rows, err := db.Query(`
                INSERT INTO users (email, password_digest, created_at, modified_at)
                        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
                        RETURNING id
                `, ua.GetEmail(), digest, createdAt, modifiedAt)

        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        defer rows.Close()

        var id int
        for rows.Next() {
                if err := rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
                        return err
                }
        }

        ua.SetID(id)

        return nil
}
```

Is there a better way to model these separate actions so the UserActions can be mocked when testing the DB/Store functions? I tried storing the `User` struct as part of the interface, something such as:

```
type UserAction {
    SetTimestamps()
    CreateDigest() (string, error)
    VerifyPassword() error
    ComparePassword(password string) error
    User() *User
}
```

This however causes cyclical imports when creating mocks, and also opens up all fields, which are already arguably available since the model's fields are exportable

Comment: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Comment: Your code is wrong at some point wouldn't this line `func (db *DB) CreateUser` be `func (db *UserStore) CreateUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* your user should be a concrete type, and you should use an interface to mock your store.

For instance, a project structure like this makes sense to me:

```
cmd/
   server/
      user.go
      user_test.go
      main.go
      store.go
mysql/
   mysql.go
   user.go
   user_test.go
user.go
user_test.go
```

Your user model is at the root, in `user.go`. This file will contain your `User` struct, and the functions that will operate on it, like `CreateDigest`. These functions should be tested in `user_test.go`.

It is worth mentioning that at your root, your package should not be `main`, your package name should be the name of your project, we will call it `myapp`.

Your `mysql`, `postgres`, etc. should also be a concrete implementation. You may have a function in that package like:

```
func (m *MySQL) InsertUser(u *myapp.User) error
```

This function should be tested in `mysql/user_test.go`.

And finally, we can put it all together in `server`. This is the binary you actually deploy or run.

In `cmd/server/store.go`, you should create an interface that will be implemented by `mysql`.

In `cmd/server/user_test.go` it is very easy to mock this so that you do not have to hit the real database. I am a believer in that your interfaces should live in your client. In this case, `server` is a client of `mysql`.

In `cmd/server/user.go` you may have functions that look like this:

```
func CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var u myapp.user
  err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err) // don't do this for real
  }

  d := myapp.CreateDigest(u.Password)
  u.Digest = d

  // s is the interface, defined in `cmd/server/store.go`, but is implemented by mysql
  err = s.InsertUser(&u)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  // Since we pass a pointer, you can have your store set the ID of the user
  fmt.Println(u.ID)
}
```

Now that you have a better separation of concerns, everything should be easy to test, and making changes to existing code is easy.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful.